# Is ContactsContract.Contacts.LAST_TIME_CONTACTED reliable?

Tags: android

when I read the results on my phone of `ContactsContract.Contacts.LAST_TIME_CONTACTED` it is usually 0 even for people I phone often... but there are a few fields with numbers other than 0.

Is this not a reliable field to use? I don't understand why most of the people I phoned with this phone are 0

Answer (score 3):

This API field is screwed up by many device manufactures.

According to our testing, the API call `Contacts.markAsContacted` does one of the following on different manufacture devices:

- adds one to `TIMES_CONTACTED` and updated `LAST_TIME_CONTACTED` (as it should, this is easily tested on plain Android devices like all Nexus devices)
- adds one to `TIMES_CONTACTED` but doesn't update `LAST_TIME_CONTACTED` (if i'm not mistaken, this is the case on all samsung devices)
- doesn't do anything.

Bottom line, you can't really trust `TIMES_CONTACTED` and `LAST_TIME_CONTACTED` to work well on all devices.

There's an open bug for Android here:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8784&q=LAST_TIME_CONTACTED&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

feel free to star it...

Comment: Great review, thanks for laying this out for people thinking of using this method.